# Local notifications on gps services off

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am using location services on background in my app for fetching user location.

I want to get local notifications from my application when the user switches off the location services in settings page.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Which iOS version? I assume you're using iOS SDK instead of Cordiva / PhoneGap , Unity3D , etc, right ? and *what have you tried* ?

Comment: Last, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062201/continously-check-for-location-services-enabled-in-ios)

Comment: we are using ios6 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :
It's called every time user disable/enable location services in settings

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use **local notification**? Why not **UIAlertView**?

I would like to suggest you to use UIAlertView as it will inform the user what to do when he/she opens the app. For local notification, you can schedule it. Most likely, the user will not see the notification when the user is on the foreground of the app (when open). And you are not able to know if the app has the right to use location or not if the user never opens the app.

By using didFailWithError delegate method from locationManager, you will be able to know if the user allows your app to get the location or not.

You will have to implement the locationManager delegate method like below:-

```
- (void)locationManager: (CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error
{

switch([error code])
{
    case kCLErrorNetwork: // general, network-related error
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Network Error" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
        break;
    case kCLErrorDenied:{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"YOUR APP NAME doesn't work without Location Services enabled. To turn it on, go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
        break;
    default:
    {

    }
        break;
}
}
```

If you insist want to implement local notification, replace the above UIAlertView with local notification code.

Comment: If user opens the application only,alertview can be displayed,so I want to use local notification which will be displayed on lock screen too.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, you may implement the local notification to replace the above UIAlertView. In order for your app to schedule the local notification, you still have to open your app to check the app's location status.

Comment: What if user opens the app and terminated the app and also enabled the "Use Always" for data services in the location usage settings, can I receive local notification in that case.